# how can I pull out the contents from an email and write them in a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, email

How can I make it so when a user email's to my email address their email text/information is written into a mysql table? So basically extract the contents of a new email and write them into mysql table.

I tried this but I get nothing:

```
<?php 
$imap = imap_open("{gmail.com}", "username", "password"); 

if( $imap ) { 

     //Check no.of.msgs 
     $num = imap_num_msg($imap) 

     //if there is a message in your inbox 
     if( $num >0 ) { 
          //read that mail recently arrived 
          echo imap_qprint(imap_body($imap, $num)); 
     } 

     //close the stream 
     imap_close($imap); 
} 
?>
```

We are using an exchange server..I am a coop student so I am not really advanced at this.

I tried this as a test to see if it works, logging in gmail to read email. It didnt work.

```
<?php

// connect to the mailbox
$m_mail = imap_open("{mail.https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2}INBOX", "username", "password");

//get all messages
$m_search=imap_search ($m_mail, 'ALL ');


// Order results starting from newest message
rsort($m_search);

//loop through and do what's necessary 
foreach ($m_search as $onem) {

    //get imap header info for obj thang
    $headers = imap_headerinfo($m_mail, $onem);
    $head = imap_fetchheader($m_mail, $headers->Msgno);
    $body = imap_body($m_mail, $headers->Msgno, FT_INTERNAL );

  echo $body;

}

//purge messages (if necessary)
imap_expunge($m_mail);

//close mailbox 
imap_close($m_mail);

?>
```

Comment: 1.You're missing ';' a the end of imap_num_msg($imap); 2. make sure you're really connected to your server. If you're getting back $imap might be FALSE whcih means not connected 3. ensure that you have the right server specified too - gmail.com looks off

Answer (score 1):

use IMAP functions for that. Set up another email account if necessary. Here's the example code:

```
// connect to the mailbox
$m_mail = imap_open("{mail.YOURHOST.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "address@YOURHOST.com", "YOURPASSWORD");

//get all messages
$m_search=imap_search ($m_mail, 'ALL ');


// Order results starting from newest message
rsort($m_search);

//loop through and do what's necessary 
foreach ($m_search as $onem) {

    //get imap header info for obj thang
    $headers = imap_headerinfo($m_mail, $onem);
    $head = imap_fetchheader($m_mail, $headers->Msgno);
    $body = imap_body($m_mail, $headers->Msgno, FT_INTERNAL );

    //
   DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO HERE - insert to the database, etc

}

//purge messages (if necessary)
imap_expunge($m_mail);

//close mailbox 
imap_close($m_mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

read your mailbox via pop3 or imap and add the new emails to your database

Take a look a this class: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Answer (score 0):

you could read the pop3/imap in some intervals.
other method would be to redirect your email to a php script. I don't know which email system you are using on your server but here is an [example with postfix](http://jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/).

the pop3/imap method is easier and you don't need to edit your server configs but the second method is faster because your script will start as it receives an email.