# IMAP: Getting emails from gmail

Tags: php, imap

I want to get emails from gmail, but I want to get the folder 'All Mail'

I have the following:

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}';
$user = 'myUser';
$password = 'myPassword';
$connection = imap_open($server, $user, $password);
$count = imap_num_msg($connection);
echo $count;
```

The echo however is echoing the emails in the inbox only, how can I make it read a certain folder, or all the folders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this to get all mail:

```
$server = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}[Gmail]/All Mail';
```

We went round and round on this awhile; see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8178514/776695

As stated here, use `imap_list` to see which individual folders are available

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`imap_status`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-status.php) to get the message count for a given folder.

To find all folders, you can use [`imap_list`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-list.php).

To find messages in folders, you can for instance use [`imap_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php). These can then be accessed using e.g. [`imap_headerinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php) and [`imap_body`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php)

For further information, please consult [the documentation of the IMAP functions in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php).

Comment: Thanks! But then how do I access the messages in those folders?

Comment: @luqita Edited answer with a few suggestions.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I am not sure what to do, what to search for, etc.

Comment: If you need examples, see the documentation linked or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157980/how-can-i-pull-out-the-contents-from-an-email-and-write-them-in-a-mysql-table .